# Change pictureBox.Image with c# = FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

i have a small app in C# winform. It work great but i don't understand how to change the image of a picture box in code :

i have this directory for my image :

myProjectDirectory/bin/Pics/myImage.jpg

and this code give me an FileNotFoundException :

```
this.imgInvader.Image = Image.FromFile("../Pics/invader2.jpg");
```

i don't understand because i see on stackoverflow that FromFile method begin at bin/Release. So a ../Pics/myImage.jpg should work no ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the relative path of the image.

```
this.imgInvader.Image = Image.FromFile(@"bin\Pics\invader2.jpg");
```

Here give the path from the location where your code behind file is located. Suppose if your file is in root directory and if your images are in `bin/Pics/` folder then the above code works. It automatically gets the path related to the location the program is running from.

Comment: hi, this is doesn't work, i have the same message "FileNotFoundException".

My project is on E:\DropBox\Dropbox\C#\Proejcts\MyProjects\bin\Pics

Comment: Can you try to upload a screenshot of the exception so that I can know what is wrong.

Comment: here the message : https://www.dropbox.com/s/hujzkko91gflov8/exceptionMessage.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Just to make sure, can you check if you have that image in bin/Pics folder and also check the spelling.

Comment: Also can you tell me the location of the file where you are writing this code. Its directory.

Comment: yeah sure, here my directory -> E:\DropBox\Dropbox\C#\1.7 - Pise Invaders - gestion niveau\Pise Invaders\Pise Invaders\bin\Pics 

and here i have a JPEG file name invader2.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87726/discussion-between-barnab21-and-sailesh-chowdary-doppalapudi).

Comment: yeah sure, here my directory -> E:\DropBox\Dropbox\C#\1.7 - Pise Invaders - gestion niveau\Pise Invaders\Pise Invaders\bin\Pics and here i have a JPEG file name invader2.jpg
and my file with this code : E:\DropBox\Dropbox\C#\1.7 - Pise Invaders - gestion niveau\Pise Invaders\Pise Invaders

Answer (score 1):

Trying to reference image files that are outside the executable output directory is incredibly fragile. There are lots of ways it can go wrong (unfortunately, there's not enough context in your question for anyone to know exactly which of these ways is your specific problem).

If you must use files on disk to store your image resources, then they should be copied into the *build* output directory (i.e. "Release") and referenced there. Add the file to your Visual Studio project, select it, and in the properties window, set the "Build Action" value to "Content". If the file is in a folder under the project, then it will also be copied to a folder of the same name in the output directory.

If you do use files on disk, the other thing to make sure you do is find the executable's directory (e.g. via `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)`) and then combine that with your expected relative path (e.g. just the file name, or the file name under whatever folder/subdirectory you gave it in the project, if you did) using the `Path.Combine()` method, and then using *that* absolute file name as the source. Otherwise, your code can be confused by changes in the current directory made elsewhere in your program (basically, don't ever rely on the current directory…global state like that is too easy to get mixed up, once you get into the habit of using it).

For example:

```
string exeDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
string imageFileName = Path.Combine(exeDirectory, "invader2.jpg");
```

Now, all that said, IMHO it is probably a better idea to add your images as resources in the executable itself, and then reference them from the `Properties.Resources` class. Then the images are always with the executable, because they are in the same file. The code is a lot easier too, because you're just referencing properties in the `Resources` class that return the actual `Image` objects you need.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous comment stated, using resources outside of your exe is not advised however you can still do this by using the `Path.GetDirectoryName` Method.

I am left to question why your resources are based outside of your exe, why not embed it into your resources located in  properties > resources.resx and simply call it with `imgInvader.Image = Properties.Resources.FileNamehere;` it is a lot safer than trusting the external environment.